# How do I explicitly declare the type of the variable as object in Haxe?

Tags: object, variables, haxe

If I have a variable called `str` that is a String, I can do the following

```
var str:String = "value";
```

However, I don't know what kind of type I need to use for a generic object like this

```
var myObj:???? = {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2
}
```

I know I don't need to declare it but I still want to know what the proper text is in place of ????

`Type.typeof()` says it's a `TObject` but I can't use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on reusing this structure you should look at defining a Class or [Typedef](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-typedef.html). Otherwise, you don't necessarily have to provide a type. You could just do the following and let the compiler assign its own type:

```
var myObj = {
      key1: "foo",
      key2: "bar"
    };
```

If using a typedef you would do like:

```
typedef FooBar = {
  var foo : String;
  var bar : String;
}
var myObj:FooBar = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar"
};
```

Comment: Thank you, so there is no "Object" type that I can use similar to "String" or "Int" or "Bool"?

Comment: Doing it the first way is called an anonymous structure: https://haxe.org/manual/types-anonymous-structure.html 
I suppose it does whatever an Object can do.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on key types but you might want something like this:

```
    var myObj:{key1:String, key2:String} = {
      key1: "foo",
      key2: "bar"
    };
```